# Create TableRows dynamically

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, mobile, tablerow

I'm trying to create "cells" dynamically, they need an image and 3 TextViews. I chose to use the TableLayout and my cells are TableRows.
I've tried this:

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/01/android-creating-tablerow-rows-inside-a-tablelayout-programatically/

But cells do not appear (yes, I changed the color of the text :-))

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?
And, someone suggests something better than TableRow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a WebView and then your table can be created/manipulated using HTML/js (there are excellent jQuery plugins).
I've tried a couple of times using TableLayout and then I've switched to the WebView/HTML solution.

It really depends on the design of your app.

Comment: Great, I'll search something. Do you have some examples using it?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I cannot share the code.

I've been using a jQuery plugin called jqGrid. 
I have an HTML file containing the javascript and an empty DIV where I'll place the table.

I load the HTML into the WebView `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");`

And then I manipulate the table calling the javascript function from the activity:
`webView.loadUrl("javascript:doSomething();");`